# The session variable is lost, in Django

Tags: python, django, session

In a system that should be multi-company, I use context_processors.py to load company options, by selecting from the sidebar. The user can change companies at any time.

When the user selects a company, the option is recorded in a session variable.

It happens that when the user changes pages, the information of the session variable is lost.

What am I doing wrong or failing to do? Is there a better way to do this?

Relevant code snippets follow:

context_processors.py

```py
from apps.client.models import Client

def units (request):
    # Dictionary with business options
    clients = Client.objects.values ​​(
        "client_id",
        "company_id__name",
    )
    clients_list = []
    for client in clients:
        clients_list.append (
            {
                'client_id': client ['client_id'],
                'name': client ['company_id__name']
            }
        )
    return {'clients_list': clients_list}
```

base.html

```html
# System base page.
# Displays the list of business options.
<select class = "form-control select2">
<option value = "{{request.session.unit_id}}"> {{request.session.unit_id}} </option>
{% for client in clients_list%}
<option value = "{{client.client_id}}"
{% if request.session.unit_id == client.client_id%}
selected
{% endif%}>
{{client.client_id}}
</option>
{% endfor%}
</select>
...
```

```
# Whenever a company is selected ...
<script>
$ ("# select_unit"). click (function () {
    var option_id = $ (this) .val ();
    var url = "{% url 'home: set_unit'%}";
    $ .ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: {'unit_id': option_id},
        success: function () {}
    });
});
</script>
```

view.py

```py
# View that registers the variable in the session.
def set_unit (request):
    unit_id = request.GET.get ("unit_id")
    request.session ['unit_id'] = unit_id
```

settings.py

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'apps.core.middleware.AppMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_globals.middleware.Global',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'apps.home.context_processors.units',
            ],
        },
    }
]
```

Comment: your `set_unit` view doesn't return anything? I think that could be a problem. How is it called?

Comment: set unit always feeds the session correctly. It turns out that when switching pages the session no longer shows the value that the user had selected

Comment: I don't understand. a view always has to return an HttpResponse. Yours doesn't.

Comment: the set_unit view just takes the chosen company and arrow on the session variable. The page should not be redirected, it should stay where it is. Remember that select for company selection is a sidebar component, so there should be no page redirection. And the problem occurs exactly in this fact: after choosing a company the user accesses any page of the system - at this moment the session variable that was defined is lost.

Comment: I think maybe I'm not setting the session variable correctly, maybe it's missing some detail.

Comment: You need to explain how and where you call your `set_unit` view. Django only saves the session at the end of the request cycle, in middleware. If before that an exception is raised (which will happen because your view isn't returning anything), the session won't be saved. So please answer my first question instead of saying you're doing it right. Obviously you're not doing it right, otherwise it would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: set_unit is called by ajax script, above posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view that’s setting a session variable needs to return a response. Since you’re calling it with Ajax, a `JsonResponse` with simple `{'status': 'ok'}` dictionary is fine. Add this line at the end of `set_unit`:

```
return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
```

If you look at your browser dev tools network tab or in your console you’ll see that currently your request is generating an error since a view should not return `None`. That’s the reason the session isn’t saved and the new state of the session variable not persisted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that u didn't set that the session was modified, after change the session value.

```
request.session.modified = True
```

Another option is add in your settings.py:

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST=True
```

Comment: You don’t need to set that the session is modified if you’re just changing a simple key-value pair, Django detects those changes automatically. [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved)

Comment: I didn't knew that. Thanks!